# How to make a smooth live wallpaper?

Tags: ios, wallpaper, apple-live-photos

I intend to create live wallpapers for iphones (iOS 9 and later) programmatically.

I used [the LoveLiver project](https://github.com/mzp/LoveLiver) to create some live wallpapers.

I also tried the free app Live Edit on App Store to create some.

I even created some myself (by taking live photos with an iphone 6s and then set them as wallpaper).

However, all of them are not as smooth as [this demo live wallpaper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqORzHsjU7k).

Especially the moment right after I press on the screen: For the demo, the transition from static to dynamic is very smooth. However, for all other live wallpapers I mentioned above, it's blur at fisrt, and then it becomes dynamic, hence it's not very smooth.

Do you have any idea about what is the cause of this difference?

Thank you.